# Haskell: How to read in command line args as int?

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I am trying to get an int value from the command line and pass it to the `disp` function.

```
import System(getArgs)

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    disp $ read $ head args :: Int

disp n = take n $ repeat 'S'
```

The error given by ghc is

```
 Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `[Char]'
 In the expression: disp $ read $ head args :: Int
 In the expression:
   do { args <- getArgs;
            disp $ read $ head args :: Int }
 In an equation for `main':
     main
       = do { args <- getArgs;
                  disp $ read $ head args :: Int }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use read :: (Read a) => [Char] -> a to parse the argument as an int (Int is an instance of Read)

Comment: I am using `read` above. Using `read` from prelude works. Eg: `take (read $ head ["5", "4", "3"] ::Int) [x | x <- [1..19]]` works giving `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: just remove that `:: Int` you added there. It'll work out which `read` to use.

Comment: I am getting error: Couldn't match expected type `IO b0' with actual type `[Char]'

Comment: that's becasue you need to ad `print` there: `print $ disp ...`

Comment: You can use ```replicate n 'S'``` instead of ```take n $ repeat 'S'```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is with precendence: Type signatures always try to apply to the whole expression (only scoped using parenthesis). So your `disp $ read $ head args :: Int` parses as `(disp $ read $ head args) :: Int`, which is obviously not correct. You can either use parenthesis like so:

```
disp (read $ head args :: Int)
```

or omit the type signature, as GHC can infer it in this case:

```
disp $ read $ head args
```

This code still won't work as-is, because you're in the IO monad so you need to produce IO actions. You can do this by printing the result, for example:

```
putStrLn $ disp $ read $ head args
```

Comment: Yes that works! "> you're in the IO monad so you need to produce IO actions" I am getting input inside the IO monad, is it mandatory to produce IO output as opposed to just return value that's not of type IO? Haskell noob here. Okay I should read more on IO, but any thoughts on this would be helpful too.

Comment: @kadaj All statements in a IO-do-block must return IO actions. You can, however, assign variables that can be of any type using let: `let myDispResult = disp $ read $ head args`.

Comment: You don't have to produce output, but you do have to create an IO action. If you want to return the calculated value, you can use `return`, which wraps the value in the IO monad. That said, `main`'s type has to be `IO ()`, not `IO String`, so that won't work in this case.

Answer (score 11):

You can encapsulate pulling an integer command-line argument like so:

```
getIntArg :: IO Int
getIntArg = fmap (read . head) getArgs
```

Which works because Monads are Functors. Or you can do the same thing with `liftM`.

That way your `main` function just becomes:

```
main = do
    n <- getIntArg
    disp n
```

Provided you add some type of print function to `disp` as discussed in the other answers.

Answer (score 5):

Just remove that explicit type you added there, and it'll work. Have faith in type inference. :) Add `print $ ...` there, or something similar, to correct the new error.

What happens is, the type of `take` is known, so the type of the argument that `disp` expects is known too. It is `Int`. So the appropriate `read` will be applied.

Do less, get done more.

Comment: But `disp` produces a `String`, so you probably want to add `putStrLn`.

Comment: @kosmikus or print. but that's besides what was asked.

Comment: I was pointing it out because you said "and it'll work" which is misleading if there's an independent type error. But yes, `print` will of course work as well.

Comment: @kosmikus The "it" I had in mind was not the "it" that you had in mind. :) My "it" stood for *"trying to get an int value from the command line and pass it to the disp function."*, as asked.